# How to recover integers?

Tags: java, android, split

I get a string and I have to retrieve the values

Je pense que nous devons utiliser le ".slit"

```
if (stringReceived.contains("ID")&& stringReceived.contains("Value")) {
```

here is my character string:

```
I/RECEIVER: [1/1/0 3
I/RECEIVER: :32:11] 
I/RECEIVER: Timestam
I/RECEIVER: p=946697
I/RECEIVER: 531 ID=4
I/RECEIVER: 3 Value=
I/RECEIVER: 18
```

I receive the value 1 byte by 1 byte.
I would like to recover the value of Timestamp, Id and Value..

Comment: you can use `String.indexOf()`, `String.subString()`, `String.split()`, etc to parse your string.

Comment: what would be the most efficient way to do this however. i think that is a much more interessting question

Comment: will the format of string remain same?

Comment: no, it can change, but there will always be "Timestamp=XXX" "ID=XXX" "Value=XXX"

Comment: I'd split by `=` first, then split 2nd, 3rd and 4th part by ` ` (space), and took 1st part of the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use regex for that. Something like:

```
 String example="[11/2/19 9:48:25] Timestamp=1549878505 ID=4 Value=2475";          
        Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(".*Timestamp=(\\d+).*ID=(\\d+).*Value=(\\d+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(example);
        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Timestamp is:" + matcher.group(1));
            System.out.println("Id is:" + matcher.group(2));
            System.out.println("Value is:" + matcher.group(3));
        }
```

If the order of tokens can be different (for example ID can come before Timestamp) you can also do it. But since it looks like log which is probably structured I doubt you will need to.

Comment: from what i got, it doesnt seem like it's nessecarily structured the same way every time

Comment: I assumed it is because it looks like some kind of a log ;) Otherwise we can also look for the fields one by one.

Comment: can you explain to me what is (\\ d +) ?

Comment: \\d is digit + is 1 or more. So it becomes one or more digits collected in a group because of the brackets. Means - get this sequence of digits

Comment: Hello, I have a new problem. I receive the value 1 byte by 1 byte. How to modify the code already used? I/RECEIVER: [1/1/0 3
I/RECEIVER: :32:11] 
I/RECEIVER: Timestam
I/RECEIVER: p=946697
I/RECEIVER: 531 ID=4
I/RECEIVER: 3 Value=
I/RECEIVER: 18

Answer (score 2):

First `[11/2/19 9:48:25]` seems unnecessary so let's remove it by jumping right into "Timestamp".

Using `indexOf()`, we can find where **Timestamp** starts.

```
// "Timestamp=1549878505 ID=4 Value=2475"
line = line.substring(line.indexOf("Timestamp"));
```

Since each string is separated by space, we can split it.

```
// ["Timestamp=1549878505", "ID=4" ,"Value=2475"]
line.split(" ");
```

Now for each tokens, we can substring it using index of '=' and parse it into string.

```
for(String token: line.split(" ")) {
    int v = Integer.parseInt(token.substring(token.indexOf('=') + 1));
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

```
String text = "Timestamp=1549878505 ID=4 Value=2475";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ID=(\\d)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
```

output
4

Answer (score 2):

A simple regex is also an option:

```
private int fromString(String data, String key) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(key + "=(\\d*)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        return Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    }
    return -1;
}

private void test(String data, String key) {
    System.out.println(key + " = " + fromString(data, key));
}

private void test() {
    String test = "[11/2/19 9:48:25] Timestamp=1549878505 ID=4 Value=2475";
    test(test, "Timestamp");
    test(test, "ID");
    test(test, "Value");
}
```

prints:

> Timestamp = 1549878505
>
> ID = 4
>
> Value = 2475

Answer (score 1):

You can try that:

```
        String txt= "[11/2/19 9:48:25] Timestamp=1549878505 ID=4 Value=2475";
        String re1= ".*?\\d+.*?\\d+.*?\\d+.*?\\d+.*?\\d+.*?\\d+.*?(\\d+).*?(\\d+).*?(\\d+)";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
        if (m.find())
        {
            String int1=m.group(1);
            String int2=m.group(2);
            String int3=m.group(3);
            System.out.print("("+int1+")"+"("+int2+")"+"("+int3+")"+"\n");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code, You will find your timestamp at index `0`, id at `1` and value at `2` in List.

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("=\\d+");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stringToMatch);

    final List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String ans = matcher.group(0);
        matches.add(ans.substring(1, ans.length()));
    }
```

Explaining the regex

`=` matches the character `=` literally

`\d*` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

`*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible